# How to call a scala.html file from a scala.html file in a different directory

Tags: scala, playframework

I have two scala.html files.

1. `views/receivables/snippet/account_types.scala.html`
2. `views/attendance/add_attendance.scala.html`

If I want to call 1st scala.html file from 2nd scala.html file or the other way around, how should I call since the files are in different directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a package `admin_views` under the `views` package and added there a `test.scala.html` template.
Then in one of my views from the `views` package I reference that other package view in this way:
`@views.html.admin_views.test()`

Everything from under the `views` package is compiled to `views.html` so this is the reason.
Thus in your case it would be `views.html.receivables.snippet.account_types()`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem doing this:

I have html scala file in package `views.process.popupFindProcess.scala.html`

i call this file in package `views.itens.createIten.scala.html` adding a 
`@import process.popupFindProcess` after variable declaration in top of my scala html page and add `@popupFindProcess()` to include page.